# SQL Server 2005: Why Name Transactions?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, nested-transactions

I've been sorting out the whole nested transaction thing in SQL server, and I've gleamed these nuggets of understanding of behavior of nested trans':

- When nesting transactions, only the
  outermost commit will actually
  commit.
- "Commit Trans txn_name", when nested
  , will always apply to the innermost
  transaction, even if txn_name refers
  to an outer transaction.
- "ROLLBACK TRAN" (no name) , even in
  an inner transaction, will rollback
  all transactions.
- "ROLLBACK TRAN txn_name" - txn_name must
  refer to the outermost txn name.
  If not, it will fail.

Given these , is there any benefit of naming transactions? You cannot use it to target a specific tranasction, either for commit or rollback.
Is it only for code commenting purposes?

Thanks,

Yoni

Comment: One more reason, not worth an answer IMO, is [here](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/code-to-show-rolled-back-transactions-after-a-crash/).

Answer (score 9):

Effectively it's just a programmers aide memoire. If you're dealing with a Tx that has a number of inner transactions, giving each meaningful names can help you make sure that the tranactions are appropriately nested and may catch logic errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can have procedures rollback only their own work on error, allowing the caller to decide wether to abandon the entire transaction or recover and try an alternate path. See [Exception handling and nested transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/) for a procedure template that allows this atomic behavior.

Comment: Really?  But the doc says that you can't roll back an inner nested transaction, you can only roll back the outermost transaction.  I'm not disputing you because I haven't tried it, I'm just curious which is the way it actually works.

Comment: You can rollback to a save point. I reckon that's not the same as a named transaction, but I think that is what you're really after.

Comment: Remus -  Good point about the save point. Otherwise , (If not using Save Points, which I currently am not)   , no benefit?

Comment: Naming transactions can catch application errors when the transaction nesting is not the one expected by the developers, because if a compoenent attmpts to roll back the wrong name, an error is generated.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense.  Nested transactions != savepoints.

Comment: BTW, I read your article you linked in your response. It looks like a great pattern, and I am going to try it out going forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to roll back part of your work, like a nested transaction. Does not always work as intended.
Stored procedures using old-style error handling and savepoints may not work as intended when they are used together with TRY … CATCH blocks: [Avoid mixing old and new styles of error handling.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2008/11/15/avoid-mixing-old-and-new-styles-of-error-handling.aspx)

Already discussed here [@@ERROR and/or TRY - CATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111501/error-and-or-try-catch)

Comment: But it doesn't roll back part of your work.  Nesting transactions merely increments @@TRANCOUNT.  Rolling back a nested transaction rolls back the whole thing.  Unless you're talking about save points.