# What happens if you don't commit a transaction to a database (say, SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, commit

Suppose I have a query:

```
begin tran
-- some other sql code
```

And then I forget to commit or roll back.

If another client tries to execute a query, what would happen?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

As long as you don't **COMMIT** or **ROLLBACK** a transaction, it's still "running" and potentially holding locks.

If your client (application or user) closes the connection to the database before committing, any still running transactions will be rolled back and terminated.

Comment: mmm, ok I figure out this was creating some sort of lock. I wasn't sure that closing the connection would actually get me out of this state. the problem was that I was getting an error when I try to commit. now I closed the connection and it all worked.

Comment: Side note: If using Management Studio, closing the query window will close the connection

Comment: Would restarting the server (off of a hard power loss) also cause a rollback?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: yes, definitely

Comment: I'v got another type of question. E. g. I'm using EF6 transactions (cntx.database.BeginTransaction with read committed). If I Commit or Rollback transaction I see TM:Commit/Rollback Transaction message in SQL Server profiler and the table is unlocked. 
But if I kill IIS process (with my app) after transaction has been opened, locked tables become unlocked (I guess connection with the EF is interrupted and the transactions are closed automatically) and no rollback messages is displayed in SQL profiler. 
Why? Is it correct? Will SQL server close transaction anyway?

Comment: Keep in mind that SQL Server Management Studio auto commits if you close the query window/connection, by default.

Comment: Note that when the client closes the connection while a transaction is active, it is not always rolled back - this depends on the client and the db. E.g. when a Java app closes a connection to an Oracle db, any open connections are automatically committed.

Comment: @Avid you're correct with Java/Oracle but the question was about SQL Server

Comment: seems the DB should throw an error if the Trans is never committed or times out, but does not. To me this logic is backwards from anything else the database does. Everything else seems to timeout, why not a transaction?

Comment: everyone should take care of the "potentially holding locks" part of this reply.

Answer (score 51):

You can actually try this yourself, that should help you get a feel for how this works.

Open two windows (tabs) in management studio, each of them will have it's own connection to sql.

Now you can begin a transaction in one window, do some stuff like insert/update/delete, but not yet commit. then in the other window you can see how the database looks from outside the transaction. Depending on the isolation level, the table may be locked until the first window is committed, or you might (not) see what the other transaction has done so far, etc.

Play around with the different isolation levels and no lock hint to see how they affect the results.

Also see what happens when you throw an error in the transaction.

It's very important to understand how all this stuff works or you will be stumped by what sql does, many a time.

Have fun! GJ.

Comment: ok but will the transaction be written to log at very least before issuing the commit? For example, say I want to start a transaction run an insert command and "do something else" before I execute commit. will my insert command be written to log? that way if the server crashes before executing commit..it can come back to where it was and I can just issue commit later(whenever I am done doing "something else").

Comment: @user1870400 It seems obvious that the answer this user would have given is... try it.

Answer (score 23):

Transactions are intended to run completely or not at all. The only way to complete a transaction is to commit, any other way will result in a rollback.

Therefore, if you begin and then not commit, it will be rolled back on connection close (as the transaction was broken off without marking as complete).

Comment: That's how it should be, but it's not always the case.

Comment: ...such as mySQL's MyISAM, which doesn't *support* transactions, sure.

Answer (score 5):

When you open a transaction nothing gets locked by itself. But if you execute some queries inside that transaction, depending on the isolation level, some rows, tables or pages get locked so it will affect other queries that try to access them from other transactions.

Answer (score 4):

depends on the isolation level of the incomming transaction.

[Sql transaction isolation explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Comment: The behavior of the transactions doesn't depend on the isolation level. The amount of locks they might cause does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what data is able to be read by a connection is definitely dependant on the isolation level. If you have the isolation set to READ UNCOMMITTED you can read data not yet committed and may in fact be rolled back at some point the track, but this ensures there is no locking. If you have READ COMMITTED as your isolation level, then you can't read uncommitted rows - the second client will hang unless you use SNAPSHOT.

Answer (score 1):

**Example for Transaction**

begin tran tt

Your sql statements

if  error occurred 
    rollback tran tt
else 
    commit tran tt

As long as you have not executed  commit tran tt , data will not be changed

Comment: Note that naming transactions is not only unnecessary in MS SQL, it can give a false sense of control.  `BEGIN TRAN X ... BEGIN TRAN Y ... ROLLBACK Y` does not work, for example.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273376/sql-server-2005-why-name-transactions

Answer (score 1):

Any uncomitted transaction will leave the server locked and other queries won't execute on the server. You either need to rollback the transaction or commit it. Closing out of SSMS will also terminate the transaction which will allow other queries to execute.

Comment: In my case I only closed tab(file), where was query with executed transaction, and SSMS asked me if I want to commit transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the potential locking problems you might cause you will also find that your transaction logs begin to grow as they can not be truncated past the minimum LSN for an active transaction and if you are using snapshot isolation your version store in tempdb will grow for similar reasons.

You can use `dbcc opentran` to see details of the oldest open transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I really forget to commit a transaction. I have a query like codes below.

This stored procedure is called by .Net. When I test the function in .Net application, the exception will be captured in .Net application.

Exception message like below:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

When I realize the mistake, I have tried many times, both in .Net application and SQL Server Management Studio (2018). (In SSMS, the output statement will successfully output the result in `Results` tab, but shows the error message in `Messages` tab.)

Then I find the tables used in this transaction are locked. When I only select top 1000 without `order desc`, it can select the result. But when I select top 1000 with `order desc`, it will be running for a long time.

When I close the .Net application, the transaction was not committed (based on the data not changed in the transaction).

When I close the `EXEC ...` tab (which execute the forged commit query), SSMS will pop a warning window:

> There are uncommitted transactions. Do you wish to commit these transactions?

I have tested the both the `Yes` and `No` choices.

If I click `Yes`, the transactions are committed.

If I click `No`, the transactions aren't committed.

After I close the tab, my locked table will be released, then I can query successfully.

```sql
begin try 
    -- some process
    begin transaction
    update ...
    output ...
    

    insert ...

    -- I missing this commit statement below
    commit transaction  
end try
begin catch 
    if (xact_state()) = -1
    begin 
        rollback transaction;
        ;throw
    end;

    -- this statement I want to compare to 1, but mistake write to -1, but since the throw statement let the mistake can't be triggerd
    if (xact_state()) = 1
    begin
        commit transaction;
    end;
end catch;
```

Answer (score -4):

The behaviour is not defined, so you must explicit set a commit or a rollback:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/java.920/a96654/basic.htm#1003303

> "If auto-commit mode is disabled and you close the connection without explicitly committing or rolling back your last changes, then an implicit COMMIT operation is executed."

Hsqldb makes a rollback

```
con.setAutoCommit(false);
stmt.executeUpdate("insert into USER values ('" +  insertedUserId + "','Anton','Alaf')");
con.close();
```

result is

> 2011-11-14 14:20:22,519 main            INFO  [SqlAutoCommitExample:55] [AutoCommit enabled = false]
>   2011-11-14 14:20:22,546 main            INFO  [SqlAutoCommitExample:65] [Found 0# users in database]

Comment: This may be true for Oracle (I have no idea), but questioner is asking about MS-SQL

Comment: The first quote applies to the JDBC driver, not to the server.