# Not able to insert into mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I have just started using MySQLdb in python. I am able to create table but when I try to insert, no rows are inserted into the table and its shows that table is still empty.

```
    import MySQLdb
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","shivam","test")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    s = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS batting"
    cursor.execute(s)
    s = """create table batting (
        name varchar(50) primary key,
        matches integer(5),
        innings integer(5),
        runs integer(5),
        highest integer(3),
        strikerate integer(3),
        hundreds integer(3),
        fifties integer(3)
        )"""
    cursor.execute(s)
    s = """insert into batting(name) values(
        "shivam")"""

cursor.execute(s)
db.close()
```

Where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to `commit` your connection. Simply add:

```
cursor.execute(s)
db.commit()
```

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896479/what-happens-if-you-dont-commit-transaction-in-a-database-say-sql-server). It explains why you need to `commit`