# SQL - Table waiting for Commit/Rollback after closing session

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollback, locked

I have a large table without any indexes on it, about 27.5m rows.
I tried to delete about half of those using using `BEGIN TRAN`.
I then tried canceling the querie, but because it was taking long I decided to just close the Management Studio.
Now when I try to look into that table, it does not return anything, just keeps running.
When I run `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Tbl` it just executes without returning anything.
But when I run `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Tbl(NOLOCK)` it return 10 rows.
This tells me that it is waiting on a `Rollback/Commit` from my `BEGIN TRAN`.
I thought it would rollback automatically after closing the session and Management Studio.
 How do I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896479/what-happens-if-you-dont-commit-transaction-in-a-database-say-sql-server

Comment: maybe you should close your connection to the database?

Comment: @ProgrammingBaKa I've read that and it says that it should have rolled it back once I close the session. I have closed it but it still appears locked. How do I close connection to DB?

Comment: I would say try closing the connection as well but I thought If using Management studio the connection should be terminated/closed by closing the query window.

Comment: I did that. Closed all of the Management Studio instance I had opened. Still only works while NOLOCK is present.

Comment: To close connection have you try terminating sqlserver.exe from Task Manager or activity monitor if you have a mac?

Comment: Ending Tasks from the Task Manager worked.

Comment: Great. I will post it as an answer so people who run into the same problem can find the solution easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this worked:

Terminate/Close connection to the database would solve this. To close connection you can try terminating sqlserver.exe from Task Manager or Activity Monitor if you have a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

> Execute SP: [SP_LOCK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-lock-transact-sql)
>
> In Results you will get SPID, DBID, OBJID, INDID, TYPE, RESOURCE,
>   MODE, STATUS
>    Now check the status column, if it is showing wait then
>
> kill that SPID.   To kill a particular SPID Execute SP: Kill 65 (Where
>   65 is SPID)

[MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/171d9fa9-0a39-48ce-bc38-35623e0c1075/how-can-i-release-lock-on-tables?forum=transactsql)

Comment: Wish I would have tried this before killing the task. I will keep this in mind.