# The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION, but still getting an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, rollback

Simple query:
Before the UPDATE, the value of EffectiveStartDt is NULL
After the UPDATE and the ROLLBACK, I want it to go back to NULL

```
begin tran t1
update MasterPayor 
set EffectiveStartDt = '2020-09-17' 
where MasterPayorId = 1
commit

rollback tran t1
```

I have defined the transactions, but I'm still getting the Rollback error

Comment: You have committed the transaction immediately after your update, hence why the transaction is no longer available

Comment: where else would I do the commit.... certainly not after the rollback ??

Comment: If you want to rollback the transaction you don't need the commit. It is an either / or. If you want to commit your changes to the DB use Commit, if you want to rollback use rollback.

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you.... but then, why would anyone use COMMIT, seeing that even without that, the database gets updated, and the new values are stored.

Comment: If you use a begin tran and don't commit the transaction will be rolled back when you close the query window. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896479/what-happens-if-you-dont-commit-a-transaction-to-a-database-say-sql-server. If you don't use the begin tran then the query will be committed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COMMIT` commits the update to the Database and clears the transaction begun with the matching `BEGIN TRAN`, hence the error when you try to rollback. If you want to ROLLBACK use the `ROLLBACK` without the COMMIT:

```
begin tran t1
update MasterPayor 
set EffectiveStartDt = '2020-09-17' 
where MasterPayorId = 1

rollback tran t1
```