# What is the difference of using TRY...CATCH and @@ERROR in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

While writing transaction SQL operations,  I often use @@ERROR to find out whether some issue happened during the transaction or not. But I really don't know what is it's advantages and disadvantages over exception handling with TRY...CATCH, or which one is better. Please clarify difference between those and the scenarios at which these are useful.

Thanks in advance,
Vinu.

Comment: You might find this useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111501/error-and-or-try-catch

Comment: Must read [Error Handling in SQL 2005 and Later](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@@ERROR` will be populated as soon as an error occurs but if there is another statement executing after the error occurred `@@ERROR` will reset its value to `NULL`, so anticipating where an error can possibly occur and storing its values to a variable etc. etc. seems a lot of hassle.

Where as if you are making use of `TRY...CATCH` block, as soon as an error occurs in the `TRY` block your control jumps to the `CATCH` block and and you can make use of the system Error Functions , which can give you detailed information about the error. If no error occurs then the control never enters the `CATCH` block.

Some of them system error functions are:

```
ERROR_LINE()
EROR_MESSAGE()
ERROR_Severity()
ERROR_PROCEDURE()
ERROR_STATE()
```

Therefore I personally think using `TRY...CATCH` makes your life a lot easier as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are correct that they have some things in common, such as - they both come in handy for error handling and troubleshooting, but at the bottom line they are completely different:

- [`@@ERROR`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx) will give you the `error number for the last Transact-SQL statement executed.` i.e. It will give **information** about the error that have occurred.
- [`TRY-CATCH`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) Implements error handling. once an error happens, **the flow will be interrupted** and the code in the CATCH statement will be executed.

Personally, I usually use `TRY-CATCH` in order to stop the flow of execution upon an error, and use [ERROR_MESSAGE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx) and [ERROR_NUMBER()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175069.aspx) for information about the nature of the error.

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111501/error-and-or-try-catch/#1111532) demonstrates it quite well.