# Is it possible for @@ERROR to ever be null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to follow best practices and I see others doing an isnull check on @@ERROR but I was wondering if it is unnecessary.  Thoughts?
example:

```
SET @err = @@ERROR 
IF ISNULL(@err, 0) <> 0 ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: It only depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: According to the documentation @@error is always 0 if the previous statement did not error

Comment: For "best practices" I'd forget about @@ERROR and just use try catch.

Comment: I agree with @MartinSmith. TRY ... CATCH is best practice if that's what you're aiming for, though there's always the weird corner cases to be aware of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1111550/696808

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that there is no need of  `ISNULL` function in that Statement for that @@ERROR Variable.

Because ,it Returns 0 if the previous T-SQL statement encountered no errors.

Returns an error number if the previous statement encountered an error.

***Because @@ERROR is cleared and reset on each statement executed, check it immediately following the statement being verified, or save it to a local variable that can be checked later.***

Use the TRY...CATCH construct to handle errors. The TRY...CATCH construct also supports additional system functions (ERROR_LINE, ERROR_MESSAGE, ERROR_PROCEDURE, ERROR_SEVERITY, and ERROR_STATE) that return more error information than @@ERROR. TRY...CATCH also supports an ERROR_NUMBER function that is not limited to returning the error number in the statement immediately after the statement that generated an error.

***Note: Also we can't set NULL to the @@ERROR Variable in T-SQL.***

Comment: I switched to TRY/CATCH - works like a charm, thanks!